# Unable to return to SQL Query in MySQL Workbench after results displayed (Mac)

Tags: mysql-workbench

This is probably something really silly but using the MySQL Workbench to enter a query, I am unable to return to the query once the results are displayed.

According to all the documentation I can find, the results are meant to be returned in a lower pane from the SQL Query; though in the one I have installed (the latest version of Workbench for Mac) the results are returned onto the same panel and I am unable to return to the query.

Can anyone assist to save my sanity?

Comment: It is silly - but you're not the silly one - it's an issue with the UI. Thanks for asking the question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A screenshot would have helped, but I think your problem is simply that the splitter between the SQL editor and the resultset panel is set to completely hide the SQL editor. Try moving the mouse close to the top border, under the toolbar and see if it changes to a split cursor. Then drag the splitter down.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat - would never have thought of it.

Comment: You saved me Mike.

Comment: happening again for me on High Sierra, FWIW. new release out today (6.3.10) maybe will fix. i have the patch-fixed 6.3.9 due to disappearing grid.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in MySQL Workbench 6.1.0-6.1.7 (so far)....
See here:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72203

"Best" workaround I think is to just click on the EXPLAIN command/tab and leave it open as mentioned in one of the comments in the above link.